# Сортировка массива с массивами

Tags: javascript

помогите решить такую задачу, дан массив:

```
const input = [    
    ['сочи', 'адлер'],
    ['москва', 'cочи'],
    ['воронеж', 'киев']  
    ['адлер', 'тольяти'],
    ['кострома', 'воронеж'],
    ['тольяти', 'кострома'], 
]
```

необходимо отсортировать его в массив:

```
const output = [    
    ['москва', 'cочи'],
    ['сочи', 'адлер'],
    ['адлер', 'тольяти'],
    ['тольяти', 'кострома'],
    ['кострома', 'воронеж'],
    ['воронеж', 'киев']   
]
```

Comment: по каким полям отсортировать массив? рандомно что ли?

Comment: Последнее слово одного массива, является первым в другом массиве

Comment: Что у вас не получилось? В чем возникли сложности? + я не вижу, что бы результирующий массив был отсортирован хоть как то...

Comment: В результирующем массиве сортировка следующая: последнее слово в массиве является первым в другом массиве. Пробовал через forEach проходить по элементам массива, забирая значение второго элемента, но не сообразил как провести его сравнение с первым элементом других массивов, также пробовал действовать через sort, но также не смог сообразить необходимое мне условие... заранее извиняюсь за нубское пояснение.

Comment: у вас "сочи" в одном из массивов через англ 'c' написано

Comment: ок, мой косяк, извиняюсь, а по существу как быть?

Comment: @JohnGlebov "а по существу" -  приложите ваши попытки отсортировать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const input = [    
    ['сочи', 'адлер'],
    ['москва', 'сочи'],
    ['воронеж', 'киев'],  
    ['адлер', 'тольяти'],
    ['кострома', 'воронеж'],
    ['тольяти', 'кострома'], 
]

let first_index = input.findIndex((e,i,a) => {   
  return !a.map(item => item[1]).includes(e[0])
})

let result = input.reduce((a,e,i) => {
  if (i === first_index) return a  
  let last_city = a[a.length-1][1]  
  let next_arr = input.find(el => el[0] === last_city)  
  a.push(next_arr)   
  return a  
},[input[first_index]])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, вы супер!